# Generalised Maxima

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, representation-theory

I'm looking for a non-trivial extension of the max function. Formally
$$ M: \mathbb{C}^2 \to GL(n,\mathbb{C})  $$
with the following properties:
$$ M(z,w) = zI + M(0,w-z), \quad \forall(z,w)\in \mathbb{C}^2 $$
$$ M(z,w) - M(-z,-w) = (z+w)I, \quad \forall (z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 $$
$$ M(z,w) = \text{max}(z,w) I, \quad \forall (z,w) \in \mathbb{R^2} \subset \mathbb{C^2}. $$

**

### Work

**

For $n = 2$, we can't require additionally that $$ M(ai,bi) = iM(a,b)$$ since this gives $$ M(a,b) = M(-i^2 a, -i^2 b) = - M(-a,-b) $$ and then the map reduces to the average map for real numbers. So, if we instead require that $$ M(ai,bi) = A M(a,b), \quad \text{where} \quad A \in GL(2,\mathbb{C}) \quad \text{is fixed}, $$ we have $$ M(a,b) = A^2M(-a,-b) = A^4 M(a,b)$$ so $$ A^4 = I$$ and $$ M(a,b) = (a+b)(I-A^2)^{-1}. $$ There is only one other non-trivial option for $A$ - the square root of a Pauli matrix $P$. Since $(I-P)$ is singular for all such $P$, this is impossible for such conditions on $A$. The same argument applies to a condition of the form $$ M(ai,b) = A M(a,b). $$

Instead require $$ M(ai,b) = f(M(a,b))$$ but this feels very general. Clearly this is impossible for $n=1$. Is this possible for any $n > 1$? Is it possible for an infinite dimensional operator? Any articles or papers along these lines would be very much appreciated.